# Как сделать UPDATE WHERE в Tarantool по вторичному индексу?

Tags: lua, tarantool

Только начинаю изучать Tarantool и не могу понять, как выполнить обновление поля (компонента кортежа) по вторичному индексу?

Имеется:

```lua
local groups = box.schema.create_space('groups', {engine = 'vinyl'})

groups:create_index('group_id', {unique = true, parts = {
    {field = 1, type = 'string'}
}})
groups:create_index('active', {unique = false, parts = {
    {field = 2, type = 'unsigned'}
}})

box.space.groups:insert{'asd', 1, {name='ASD', description='asdafg'}}
```

Далее пытаюсь обновить (UPDATE groups SET active=0 WHERE active=1):

```lua
box.space.groups.index.active:update({1}, { {'=', 2, 0} })
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
error: Get() doesn't support partial keys and non-unique indexes
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно обновить запись?

И второй вопрос: если нужно делать выборку по конкретному полю (например, по description), то, правильно ли я понял, нужно обязательно создавать для него индекс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из документации (https://www.tarantool.io/ru/doc/2.2/book/box/data_model/):

> Оператор «{999}» со значением, которое используется для поиска поля,
>   соответствующего ключу в первичном индексе, является обязательным,
>   поскольку в запросе update() должен быть оператор, который указывает
>   уникальный ключ, в данном случае – field[1].

:update() поддерживает только уникальные значения ключей. Так же есть пример здесь:
https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/1.10/book/box/box_space/#update

> ```
> tarantool> -- Update by a non-unique secondary key: error --
> tarantool> s.index.sk_non_uniq:update({14}, {{'=', 2, 1300}})
> ---
> - error: Get() doesn't support partial keys and non-unique indexes
> ...
> ```

В Tarantool SQL это работает за счет поиска по вторичному индексу и апдейда по первичному ключу для каждого значения отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо, начинаю вникать. Не вижу, как здесь отметить лучший ответ..

Comment: @alex  Галочка под голосами — отметка ответа как верный.